# Error javax.naming.NameNotFoundException al invocar una clase

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio con el típico "HelloWorld" pero esta vez creando una conección JNDI a weblogic 11g con el siguiente código:

```
package com.ibytecode.client;

import java.util.Properties;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import com.ibytecode.business.HelloWorld;

public class EJBApplicationClient {
    
    private static final String LOOKUP_STRING = "HelloWorldBean";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HelloWorld bean = doLookup();
        System.out.println(bean.sayHello());
    }

    private static HelloWorld doLookup(){
        
        Properties propiedades = new Properties();
        propiedades.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
        propiedades.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", "t3://localhost:7001");
        
        InitialContext contexto = null;
        
        try {
            contexto = new InitialContext(propiedades);
            //Propiedades correctas/Hace la conección correctamente
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        HelloWorld bean = null;
        try {
              bean = (HelloWorld)contexto.lookup(LOOKUP_STRING); 
              //línea en donde falla
        } catch(NamingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bean;
    }
 }


package com.ibytecode.businesslogic;

import com.ibytecode.business.HelloWorld;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless (mappedName = "HelloWorld")
public class HelloWorldBean implements HelloWorld {

public HelloWorldBean() {
}

public String sayHello() {
    return "Hello World !!!";
}

public String sayHelloFolk(String name) {
    return "Hello floks " + name  + " see you again.";
}
}



package com.ibytecode.business;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface HelloWorld {
public String sayHello();

public String sayHelloFolk(String name);
}
```

Pero al ejecutar salen los siguientes errores:

javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Unable to resolve 'HelloWorldBean'. Resolved '' [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Unable to resolve 'HelloWorldBean'. Resolved '']; remaining name 'HelloWorldBean'[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Haciendo debug me dí cuenta que la conección a la base de datos se hacía correctamente pero todo se hiba alv en esta línea

```
bean = (HelloWorld)contexto.lookup(LOOKUP_STRING);
```

No entiendo porque sale eso si ya revisé el nombre de la clase y es el mismo. Espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Y si el LOOKUP_STRING es en realidad `HelloWorld`? Pues, ya que la anotación que le pusieron a la clase es esa...